# how to make an NSWindow blocking other Windows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow, menubar

i'm looking for a way to have a NSWindow, which is able to block other NSWindows, like the menubar does. I mean: It is not possible to drag a Window over the menubar.
Is that kind of behavior realizable for my own NSWindow?

Thanks in advance
Bijan

Answer (score 0):

NSWindow's dragging behavior automatically keeps windows from going under the menu bar — because they aren't supposed to. If you have some special case, you can override the standard dragging behavior. But think carefully before throwing away standard functionality prescribed by the HIG.

Also, it isn't possible to drag a window *over* the menu bar (rather than *under*) unless it's also over everything else, because the menu bar is normally above every other window.

Comment: Ok, if i understand that right, it is the NSWindows behavior not to go under the menubar and not that of the menubar. If so I had to modify the dragging behavior of all other windows currently running, except of mine? That sounds impossible to do..

Comment: @bijan: It's not literally impossible, but it requires some pretty sophisticated hacking and would likely break between major OS releases.

Comment: bijan: Even if you could effect this hack for all applications that use NSWindow, it would not work on any applications that don't use NSWindow (because they use X11 or Window Manager instead) or implement their own custom dragging logic.

Comment: thinking loud: so the NSWindow is likely to get a (height) property of the menubar to know where the region begins, which it may not draw above. Is it then maybe possible to set that property of the menubar to another value (without changing it's actual height)? (My Window should appear directly below the menubar.)

Comment: @bijan: AppKit has a concept of different rectangles representing the entire desktop, each screen, the area in which it will create windows and the area in which windows can be moved. The last one excludes the area that the menubar covers. Without hacking, you can't do anything with the menubar except show and hide in within your own app. Affecting other apps' windows (including the menubar) requires hacking either the entire system or the Dock.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038288/how-to-reparent-a-cocoa-window) question. There they say it is possible to move other windows using the Accessibility API or the Quartz Window Services.
Can't I just read out the other window's positions and move them, so that they do not collide with my window? Maybe triggered by a 0.1 sec. timer?