# Java: Check what program currently has 'focus'

Tags: java

Can Java check what program is currently focused (used?) and tell you what the name of the program is?

Here's an example of what I mean:

> User is using Chrome
>
> Program: "Currently focused: 'chrome.exe'

It doesn't nessecarily have to name the name of the exe file, the title of the window is fine as well.

Is this possible? if so, how would I go about making this?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. 

Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java

Comment: @mdzh, Thanks alot! I'm gonna try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you will probably need to use JNA (or something similar). Have a look at

[Windows: how to get a list of all visible windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188484/windows-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-visible-windows)

and

[How to get list of all window handles in Java (Using JNA)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717999/how-to-get-list-of-all-window-handles-in-java-using-jna)