# how to save open unsaved notepad files using java application

Tags: java

How to save an unsaved notepad file using java ?
that notepad file is not created by my program.
and the condition is there is only one notepad file opened.
i have used Process and Runtime class but not able to understand how to save the file because i dont know the path of file.

Comment: so ... you want to open a file that doesn't exist yet?

Comment: *because i dont know the path of file* Because there is no path yet?

Comment: file is not opened by program

Comment: some xyz application created notepad file and i want to save this file

Comment: it is possible to save this file ????

Comment: how can i save file plz let me know

Comment: I don't understand this question. Please edit your question and add your code

Comment: @nikhil: you can not open that file in your Java application, because the file doesn't exist yet.

Comment: but the actual thing is i am not opened this file

Comment: my task is to save this file

Comment: can i get the instance of that notepad file from process class or can i get the content of notepad file

Answer (score 0):

Some help, but it would be more robust to do it in C/C++/C# !

1 you must find your Notepad app.

it is note easy, and sure. See this: [Find out what application (window) is in focus in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206633/find-out-what-application-window-is-in-focus-in-java)

you can use JNI or JNA.

2 if you know where your app is , send a ctrl^s : see this for sending keystroke to an app. It can work if nothing is currently done inside:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(100, 100);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

[How to programmatically send a key event to any window/process in a Java App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641269/how-to-programmatically-send-a-key-event-to-any-window-process-in-a-java-app)

Note that:

- it works if notepad is in front of your screen. Otherwise
- it works if the file has already a name. If not, it only open a dialog to choose the file. You can also send a file name.