# Manage external windows using java in Mac OS and Linux

Tags: java, linux, macos

There is a question [Handle external windows using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662956/handle-external-windows-using-java), but answers are given for Windows OS only.

I would like to know is there **Linux** and **Mac OS api** to manage external windows in **java**?

If there is then how to minimize external window by name, for example?